# How to resolve Invalid character error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting an error message saying **"invalid character in identifier"** when I run this following code:
It points at the second line

> "results = open(results_path,'w')".

```
def remove_headers(file_path,header,results_path):
    results = open(results_path,'w')
    results.write(header)
    with open(file_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line == header:
                pass
            else:
                results.write(line)
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: post the full error and output you are expecting

Comment: syntactically your code is correct , can you share the stacktrace as well

Comment: Did you write this code in English mode? You might enter space or TAB in other modes.

Answer (score 1):

The usual cause of this problem is some invisible character perhaps caused by an odd keystroke combination.  The usual solution is to delete the line in question and then retype it.

If you post the full traceback, we can likely be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

your text might be encoded-

```
with open("filename.txt", "rb") as f:
    contents = f.read().decode("UTF-8")
```